# Combining Main Typescript Code and It's Dependencies in a Single File

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Is combining your main typescript code and it's dependencies in a single file for a web browser called bundling in tech speak?

How to go about this in visual studio code?

Answer (score 1):

> Is combining your main typescript code and it's dependencies in a single file for a web browser called bundling in tech speak?

Yes. Packaging so its executable by the browser.

Comment: Thank you. Is bundling releated to CommonJS, AMD, UMD module loading?

Comment: Yes. Bundling uses modules and module loaders to work on the web.

Comment: I see. So, webpack or its equivalent is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To make it, you can use [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and this plugin [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader).

---

**Update**:

lib.js

```
console.log(123);
```

index.ts

```
import './lib.js'
console.log(456);
```

The output:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
require("./lib.js");
console.log(456);
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Or the umd output

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "./lib.js"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    require("./lib.js");
    console.log(456);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

The `ts` dont help us bundle to one file so, we need to use the bundler like `webpack`, `parcel`, `rollup`... to bundle one file (with the same above code) to use at browser.

Comment: thank you .. is bundling possible without using webpack, can it be done by setting some property in the tsconfig.json?

Comment: Yes it's possible without webpack, just use another bundler. No it can't be done by setting a property in `tsconfig.json`, TypeScript is a compiler, not a bundler.

Comment: Thank you. I see now that webpack is needed in the workflow.